# Return the current value of an enum

Tags: objective-c, enums

The following code is supposed to return current item name

```
typedef enum ItemName {test1, test2} ItemName;
- (BOOL)DoItemName{return ItemName;}
```

But I receive this error:

```
error: Semantic Issue: Unexpected type name 'ItemName': expected expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `ItemName` defines a type, not a value. So writing `return ItemName` is equivalent to `return int`, which doesn't have any meaningful interpretation. The compiler tells you exactly this.

Comment: How do I return an enum and not an int then?

Comment: what i meant was, your code does not return a variable, it returns a type. If you want to return some value, first you have to declare a variable of type `ItemName` and then return it.

Comment: @evdude100: What does it *mean* to return an enum type (note: not a value, but the type itself)? That isn't something you can do in C. The *values* of that enum are `test1` and `test1`.

Comment: @Chuck I'm very confused what your getting at.